# Is laughing too loud evil?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, source-identification

I read somewhere that you need to be careful of your laugh because when you laugh too loud shaytan laugh with you. Is it true?

Comment: Laughing is part of the human nature, but a Muslim should be serious in serious matters. So laughing is not bad by default even if the prophet is more known for smiling than laughing.

Answer (score 1):

Imam Sadiq said "laughing loudly is from satan" (القهقهة من الشیطان). But it is an ethical advice and it does not mean that loud laughing is haram.

**Ref:** [Al-Kafi 2/663](https://ar.lib.eshia.ir/11005/2/664/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D9%87%D9%82%D9%87%D8%A9_%D9%85%D9%86_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D9%8A%D8%B7%D8%A7%D9%86)

Comment: As a sidenote this is also part of the wording of a hadith recorded in [Mu’jam al-Saghir Tabarani](https://shamela.ws/book/13068/1193) via Abu Hurairah and attributed to the Prophet ﷺ. Although its chain has been classed as weak by at least some.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say that laughing evilly, is evil. Whereas good humoured laughter is *halal* whether it is quiet or loud.

It's a question of taking into a persons character and it's always true in Islam that we must take that into account. After all, this is where the Whisperer slips in, into his heart, and then makes himself manifest - in evil laughter, evil intentions and evil speech.